# Why is int i = 1<<31 == -2147483648 instead of 2147483648?

Tags: c++, c++14, bit-shift, signed-integer

I was trying to understand the bitwise operation and according to me integer contains 32 bit and from LSB 0th position to MSB 31st position so if I set left shift 1 to 31 place I think I should get 2^31 and the binary representation of it would be 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 so why in am getting the result as negative ? and please correct me if I am wrong.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int i=1<<31;
    cout<<i;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because out of 2147483648 combinations one of them goes for 0 :)

Comment: `cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`

Comment: If you have a (two's complement) N bits wide signed integer, it can represent values from `-2^(N-1)` to `2^(N-1)-1`. For your 32-bit integer the max value is `2^31-1`, which is `2147483647`.

Answer (score 0):

Integer is a 32bit data type and its most significant bit stands for the sign. (That is the 32nd bit)

Therefore you're getting a negative value

Comment: You forgot to say "on some platforms"

Comment: An `int` only has 31 data bits. Shifting data into the 32nd bit invokes undefined behavior. There is no telling what result the OP will get.

Comment: Specifically, this is true on platforms that use a two's-complement representation, which is most of them. (Well, except for the part about `int` being 32 bits. That's much more variable; `int` is allowed to have any length >= 16 bits.)

Comment: Yes. On some platforms

Answer (score 0):

C++ **does not specify** the behaviour of programs that include 1<<31.

On a different platform you may get a different answer, or a compilation error, or a program that formats your drive, or **any other** behaviour.